# Stuck on Magento 1.9 Installation Wizard: Configuration stage - XAMPP Windows 8

Tags: magento

I'm trying to setup the configuration for a fresh Magento installation but it seems to be stuck on the same page.

1. I used '127.0.0.1' as Host
2. Database Name is the same as my db name in phpMyAdmin which is 'kris_magento_db'
3. Username is 'Admin'
4. 'Skip Base URL Validation Before the Next Step' is ticked
5. I have also added '127.0.0.1 www.localhost.com' to my host file.

I don't know what else I need to do or have not done. Please help

Comment: please check apache error log.Which version of php are you using?

Comment: Web server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11 I checked the Apache error log in XAMPP and here are the last three:         [Mon Jul 28 12:14:24.928533 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 7072:tid 328] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jul 28 12:14:25.092933 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 7072:tid 328] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jul 28 12:14:25.127958 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7072:tid 328] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.